# How to select the column from a Polars Dataframe that has the largest sum?

Tags: python, python-polars

I have Polars dataframe with a bunch of columns
I need to find the column with, for example, the largest sum
The below snippet sums all of the columns but I'm missing the last step of selecting the column with the largests value? I'm a Polars noob, in case it's not obvious :).
Of course, I can easily extract to numpy and find the max etc, but I'm trying to embrace Polars functionality as much as possible

```
test=pl.DataFrame(
    {
        "a": [0, 1, 3, 4],
        "b": [0, 0, 0, 0],
        "c": [1, 0, 1, 0],
    }
)
max_col=test.select(pl.col(test.columns).sum())  

shape: (1, 3)      
┌─────┬─────┬─────┐
│ a   ┆ b   ┆ c   │
│ --- ┆ --- ┆ --- │
│ i64 ┆ i64 ┆ i64 │
╞═════╪═════╪═════╡
│ 8   ┆ 0   ┆ 2   │
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do this as a melt/filter.

```
test \
    .select(pl.all().sum()) \
    .melt() \
    .filter(pl.col('value')==pl.col('value').max())
```

If you want the original shape then a single chain is a bit tougher. I'd just do it like this instead.

```
allcalc=test \
    .select(pl.all().sum())
allcalc.select(allcalc.melt().filter(pl.col('value')==pl.col('value').max()) \
       .get_column('variable').to_list())
```

The above works if there is a tie, for instance if you have:

```
test=pl.DataFrame(
    {
        "a": [0, 1, 3, 4],
        "b": [0, 0, 0, 0],
        "c": [1, 0, 1, 6],
    }
)
```

then you'll get 'a' and 'c' in either case.

Answer (score 0):

One more option is to do a `sum` and a `transpose`.
The `transpose` is an expensive operation, but here we use it on the already aggregated dataframe so the impact should not be big.

As an advantage, it makes for a short code:

```
test.select(
    test.sum().transpose(include_header=True)
    .sort('column_0', descending=True).head(1)[0,0]
    )

# Result
shape: (4, 1)
┌─────┐
│ a   │
│ --- │
│ i64 │
╞═════╡
│ 0   │
│ 1   │
│ 3   │
│ 4   │
└─────┘
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`polars.DataFrame.row`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/dataframe/api/polars.DataFrame.row.html) to get the column sums as a dictionary (`row(0, named=True)`). Then use `max` to find the column with the highest sum.

```py
test = pl.DataFrame(
    {
        "a": [0, 1, 3, 4],
        "b": [0, 0, 0, 0],
        "c": [1, 0, 1, 0],
    }
)

col_sum_dict = test.select(pl.all().sum()).row(0, named=True)
res = test.select(
    [col for col, col_sum in col_sum_dict.items() 
     if col_sum == max(col_sum_dict.values())]
)
```

Output:

```
>>> res

shape: (4, 1)
┌─────┐
│ a   │
│ --- │
│ i64 │
╞═════╡
│ 0   │
│ 1   │
│ 3   │
│ 4   │
└─────┘

>>> col_sum_dict
{'a': 8, 'b': 0, 'c': 2}
```

Note that this approach works if there is a tie, i.e. multiple columns with the highest sum. For example:

```
test = pl.DataFrame(
    {
        "a": [0, 1, 3, 4],
        "same_as_a": [0, 1, 3, 4],
        "b": [0, 0, 0, 0],
        "c": [1, 0, 1, 0],
    }
)
```

results in

```
>>> res

shape: (4, 2)
┌─────┬───────────┐
│ a   ┆ same_as_a │
│ --- ┆ ---       │
│ i64 ┆ i64       │
╞═════╪═══════════╡
│ 0   ┆ 0         │
│ 1   ┆ 1         │
│ 3   ┆ 3         │
│ 4   ┆ 4         │
└─────┴───────────┘
```